# Typescript for generic api types?

Tags: typescript

For example the api is like this `api('serviceName', {data: 1})`, this is called by the client of the api. Note that the client doesn't necessarily run on the same machine as the server.

The `api` looks like:

```
export const api = async (type: string, payload: Object) => {
  const res: any = await request
    .post(`someurl.com/api`)
    .json({data: ejson.stringify({type, payload})});
  return res;
};
```

The server side looks like something like this:

```
const apiRemote = (apiName, apiInput) => {
  return apiList[apiName](apiInput)
}
```

Note that the client can't include the `apiRemote` file directly.

How can I make the `api` to have types?

Similar but in flowtype: https://flow.org/try/#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-eShT2I7HEAnU8XqGXpCsmdg3bzIMLZGLpYWxorVcaInr3Q4hHiiUaEAgDTb8ZXC94BBVx8hSbc-FHKY9xAScZ3nQ9jyYICQPyQckB3aD93OeYlyIKRGHjIA

Some example that almost works:

```
interface S1 {
  name: 's1',
  input: number,
  output: number,
}

interface S2 {
  name: 's2',
  input: string,
  output: string,
}

interface List {
  s1: S1;
  s2: S2;
}

const a = async () => {
  type Api = <T extends keyof List>(name: T, input: List[T]['input']) => List[T]['output'];
  const api: Api = window["api"];
  const x: number = await api("s1", 2);
  const y: string = await api("s2", 's');
};
```

The problem is that I don't like to format the S1, and S2 that way. I'd like to look like this:

`type S1 = (input:Input):Output`

or something similar.

Edit 2:

```
interface S1 {
  name: 's1',
  input: number,
  output: number,
}

interface S2 {
  name: 's2',
  input: string,
  output: string,
}

type Service<T extends { input: any, output: any }> = (input: T['input']) => Promise<T['output']>

// I'd like not to have this one because now I have to enforce manually that
// s1 key in List is the same as S1["name"].
// I think makes sense for the name to be in the S1 not in this List.
interface List {
  s1: S1;
  s2: S2;
}

// I'd like to keep it in this format instead
type S = S1 | S2;

const a = async () => {
  // But in this place, if I replace `List[T]` with `S['input']` will lose the types.
  type Api = <T extends S["name"]>(name: T, input: List[T]['input']) => Promise<List[T]['output']>;
  const api: Api = window["api"];
  const x: number = await api("s1", 2);
  const y: string = await api("s2", 's');
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
interface List {
  s1: (input: number) => number;
  s2: (input: string) => string;
}

// https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26243
type Parameters<T extends (...args: any[]) => any> = T extends (...args: infer P) => any ? P : never;

const a = async () => {
  type Api = <T extends keyof List>(name: T, ...input: Parameters<List[T]>) => ReturnType<List[T]>;
  const api: Api = window["api"];
  const x: number = await api("s1", 2);
  const y: string = await api("s2", 's');
};
```

### Round 2

OK, if you want to do it that way, you can use this bit of code to construct `List` from `S` and then proceed as before:

```
// Distributive conditional type to look at each union constituent of `S`
// and keep the one with the name we are looking for.
type Lookup<SS, K> = SS extends { name: infer N } ? N extends K ? SS : never : never;
type List = {
    [K in S["name"]]: Lookup<S, K>
};
```

Further reading about conditional types is in the [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types).

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful, but I got confused on what I needed, I updated in edit2.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! That's amazing. Where can I read more about this kind of stuff? also can you put a brief explanation of what is going on. Is a bit complex and might help other people as well. Also can be converted to a more simpler way (maybe something like if else, instead of 2 ternary operators?)